# Removing char in string from specific index

Tags: c#, string

Is there any function in C# that remove from string on specific index, for example

```
string s = "This is string";

s.RemoveAt(2);
```

s is now "Ths is string"

???

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
string s = "This is string";
s = s.Remove(2, 1);
```

Output : `Ths is string`

`1st parameter` is the `starting index` from which you want to remove character and 2nd parameter is the `number of character` you want to remove

Answer (score 9):

As many others have said, there's a `Remove` method. What the other posts haven't explained is that strings in C# are immutable -- you cannot change them.

When you call `Remove`, it actually returns a **new string**; it does not modify the existing string. You'll need to make sure to grab the output of `Remove` and assign it to a variable or return it... just calling `Remove` on its own does not change the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your on extension for this using the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
     public static string RemoveAt(this string s, int index)
     {
         return s.Remove(index, 1);
     }
}
```

usage:

```
string s = "This is string";
s = s.RemoveAt(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions also.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("This is string", @"(?<=^.{2}).", ""));
```

This would remove the third character from the start.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/bWmpnt)

Comment: A regex is overkill for this situation.

Comment: yep agree regex is an overkill. I think op is asking for possibilities.

Comment: ...the good thing is, this works for almost every programming language I think. I didn't know it so cool that you posted this possiblity too.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
s = s.Remove(2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like people mentioned strings are immutable in c#, so you need to edit and assign again like:

```
string myString = "mon, ";
// Before it was mon,
myString = myString.Remove(3, 2);
// After it is mon
```

The first parameter of Remove() is the position to start removing and the second parameter is how many character to remove (inclusive).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-7.0

Comment: Other than a link to MS document this answer gives the same information as the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27669091/13664137)